# set up helper_method :current_patient Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

How can I set a helper method in my app that when I call it, recognizes a current_patient from a certain medic (can be multiple medics, and multiple patients for a medic) and access to patient :id, this would help me to associate:

Medic with a Patient with a Consultations for current_patient

I need to access on a patient and set id (patient) on a Consultation table foreign key :patient_id

in my create action in the controller I have:

```
def create
  @consultation = Consultation.new(consultation_params.merge({:patient_id => current_patient}))
  respond_to ...
end
```

Is a helper method a good way to do this?

How can I do this?

my models:

```
class Medic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patients
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :medic, :foreign_key => :medic_id
  has_many :consultations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :consultations
end

class Consultation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient, :foreign_key => :patient_id
end
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you explain your logic to identify the `current_patient`?

Comment: I've no logic in the controller to identify a current_patient, I think if I do under 'new' action: @consultation = @patient.Consultation.new rails pulls the current_patient and automatically generate a consultation new action wit the patient. but if I do this I get: undefined method `Consultation' for nil:NilClass...

Comment: Instead of focusing on how, can you try to explain the intention instead? "I want the helper method to return the patient that is currently signed in" or "When a doctor presses the patient name, the method should return that patient"

Comment: Also you are getting `undefined method 'Consultation' for nil:NilClass` because you are using the wrong case. It should be`@patient.consultations.new`. Uppercase in Ruby means that its a constant like a class name.

Comment: @max ok, I'm trying to make a app that can register medics, and the medics can create or register patients, the patients have a consultation, and consultation have 1 prescription. I'm using scaffolding for patients and consultations. I want to when 1 doctor register a patient, patient show action have a option to consultate this patient, when doctor presses consultate, consultation/new make the relationship betwen patient and consultation; this way I think is easier when I want to show Index from a consultations he had a patient. I hope this explains me. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with the routes:

```
resources :patients do
  resources :consultations
end
```

This will give us the routes for `consultations` nested under the patient:

```
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                            Controller#Action
    patient_consultations GET    /patients/:patient_id/consultations(.:format)          consultations#index
                          POST   /patients/:patient_id/consultations(.:format)          consultations#create
 new_patient_consultation GET    /patients/:patient_id/consultations/new(.:format)      consultations#new
edit_patient_consultation GET    /patients/:patient_id/consultations/:id/edit(.:format) consultations#edit
     patient_consultation GET    /patients/:patient_id/consultations/:id(.:format)      consultations#show
                          PATCH  /patients/:patient_id/consultations/:id(.:format)      consultations#update
                          PUT    /patients/:patient_id/consultations/:id(.:format)      consultations#update
                          DELETE /patients/:patient_id/consultations/:id(.:format)      consultations#destroy
```

So lets say we have a `PatientsController#index` method which shows all the patients. And in our view we have something like this:

```
<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
  <li>
    <p><%= patient.name %></p>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

So lets add a link to create the consultation:

```
<% @patients.each do |patient| %>
  <p><%= patient.name %></p>
  <ul class="actions">
    <li>
     <%= link_to "New consultation",
                 new_patient_consultation_path(patient) %>
    </li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Clicking the link would take us to `/patients/6/consultations/new`.

So in our `ConsultationsController` we can access the patient id from the params:

```
class ConsultationsController < ApplicationController

  # We use a callback so that we don't need to do 
  # @patient = Patient.find(params[:id]) in every action
  before_action :set_patient 

  # GET /patients/:patient_id/consultations/new
  def new
    @consultation = @patient.consultations.new
  end

  # POST /patients/:patient_id/consultations
  def create
    @consultation = @patient.consultations.new(consultation_params)

    # ...
  end

  # ...

  private
    def set_patient
      @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    end
    # ...
end
```

`set_patient` is just a private method belonging to the controller. This is not really a case where you would use a helper method.

Its often done when dealing with dealing with authentication since you are getting `current_user` from the session - independently from the params. If you are creating a helper method it should work everywhere.

There is one final thing you need to to get this to work, the form needs to point to `/patients/:patient_id/consultations`.

```
# app/views/consultations/_form.html.erb
<% form_for [@patient, @consultation] do |f| %>
   # .. rails does all the magic figuring out the url.
<% end %>
```

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: I follow your instructions and it works! this is what I'm looking for, but how can I show a patient.consultations in a view? the consultations that this patient has... and if I want to add prescriptions to a consultation is the same way using callback for consultation  to a prescription? thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

Comment: You would use a loop such as  `<% patient.consultations.each do |c| %>` to display them in the view.

Comment: " and if I want to add prescriptions to a consultation is the same way using callback for consultation to a prescription?" yes, but this sounds like something which merits its own controller.

Comment: ok, and if I want to show patient.consultations in a view the link_to I try <%= link_to 'Show Consultations', @patient.consultations_path %> but shows me an error: undefined method `consultations_path', in action index in the ConsultationsController I have @patient.consultations = Consultation.all thank you very much for your help

Comment: patient_consultations_path(patient_id: patient, id: consultation)

Comment: it works, in the routes for edit, show or delete I have to pass other parameters? <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_patient_consultation_path(consultation) %> and <%= link_to 'Show', consultation %> I get this error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"consultations", :id=>nil, :patient_id=>#<Consultation id: 5 ...

Comment: Run 'rake routes', it will display a list of the routes. Look at the prefix column, the helper is prefix + _path. 'edit_patient_consultation_path'

Comment: You need to pass the patient_id param as well as the consultation id.